# Orbeon 4.5 - How to pass request parameters?

Tags: orbeon

We are upgrading from Orbeon 3.9 to 4.5.

In Orbeon 3.9, we were passing request parameters to the send success URI (`oxf.fr.detail.send.success.uri`) when the user clicks on a custom submit button. We have done this by modifying `persistence-model.xml`.

Following is the code part which we used in 3.9:

```
<xforms:model id="fr-persistence-model"

    <xforms:instance id="x3params">
        <data xmlns="">
            <customerid/>
        </data>
    </xforms:instance>

    <xforms:action ev:event="xforms-model-construct-done" if="$app != '*' and $form != '*'">
        <xforms:setvalue ref="instance('g3params')/customerid" value="xxforms:get-request-parameter('customerid')" />

    <xxforms:variable name="g3customerId" as="xs:string" select="instance('g3params')/customerid"/>

    <xforms:submission id="fr-workflow-send-submission"
        resource="{$workflow-success-uri}?fr-app={$app}&amp;form={$form}&amp;docid={$document}&amp;customerid={$g3customerId}"
        relevant="{xxforms:property(string-join(('oxf.fr.detail.send.success.prune', $app, $form), '.'))}"
        validate="false" method="{$workflow-success-method}"
        serialization="{if ($workflow-success-method = 'get') then 'none' else 'application/xml'}"
        ref="if (instance('fr-workflow-send-instance') != '') then instance('fr-workflow-send-instance') else xxforms:instance('fr-form-instance')"
        replace="all"/>
```

In Orbeon 4.5, I used the `save-final` process for a custom submit.

Since `fr-workflow-send-submission` is removed in 4.5, how can I pass the request parameters to the send success URI?

Following is my properties-local.xml:

```
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.pdf" value="false"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.email.attach-pdf" value="false"/>
<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.uri.Preconstruction.*" value="http://localhost:8080/webapp/new"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.method.*.*" value="post"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.prune.*.*" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath value templates in the service URL:

```
<property
  as="xs:string"
  name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.uri.Preconstruction.*"
  value="http://localhost:8080/webapp/new?customerid={xxf:get-request-parameter('customerid')}"/>
```

Orbeon Forms passes `app`, `form` and `document` by default now. The only thing is that I notice that in your code you use `fr-app`, `form`, and `docid`. It is probably better to switch to using the standard names used by Orbeon Forms now (so `app`, `form` and `document`).

Comment: Thanks ebruchez. Its pretty simple in 4.5(compared to 3.9) in terms of passing request parameters , as I can achieve this through a simple property config.

Comment: As you noticed in my code I retrieve document_id with param name 'docid'.  is there any way to change the request parameter name as 'docid' instead of the default 'document' from the orbeon side as i don't want to change my application code?

Comment: You can try `docid={xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/document}`. But this then depends on Orbeon Forms internals.

Comment: In orbeon properties-local it does't work. I get an error while tomcat starts: '...java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 44: http://address.local/orbeon/form?iddocument={...' in properties-local I have:  <property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.myform.uri" value="http://address.local/orbeon/form?iddocument={xxf:get-request-parameter('iddocument')}"/>

Comment: Sorry about that try to change `xs:anyURI` in the property to `xs:string`. I updated the answer above.

Comment: Thank you. Now tomcat starts, but in orbeon log I get: 
Illegal character in query at index ..: http://address.local:8888/orbeon/form?iddocument={xxf:get-request-parameter('iddocument')}/crud/myapp/guid_form/form/form.xhtml  
I wonder if its correct way to add extra param because I try not exactly the same that you are doing in this post
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.myapp.*.form" value="dokForm"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.dokForm.uri" value="http://address.local:8888/orbeon/form?iddocument={xxf:get-request-parameter('iddocument')}"/>