# How do I configure or call an HTTP service in Orbeon using HTTP params and parse a JSON return value?

Tags: json, http, orbeon

I'm evaluating Orbeon to see if it can be used to build forms from one of my applications. My application exposes HTTP webservices using HTTP parameters and returning JSON.

How do I configure Orbeon PE to pass parameters to my service as HTTP parameters?

How do I parse the JSON response?

It looks like Orbeon expects XML based webservices. I've been referencing this example: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/fb-fr/call-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)Parameters:** The link from your question shows how to do it. You can also take a look at: [Orbeon 4.5 - How to pass request parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175635/orbeon-4-5-how-to-pass-request-parameters)

**2)JSON support**
If you use a submission, it's possible to use replace='text' in it to get the JSON as a text, but it would not be easy to process this information, currently it does not have support for it. There is already a task for it, but it has not been implemented yet, I meant it is for future versions. See: https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/759

But you can still use Orbeon and use a proxy in between to transform JSON to XML, then it'd handle the HTTP responses and Orbeon would get the expected response.